# A non-loop efficient way to erase from unordered_map with predicate C++11?

Tags: predicate, unordered-map, erase, remove-if

Algorithms  and member functions are suggested over looping for efficiency when working with containers.  However, associative containers (unordered_map) does not work with the erase(remove_if) paradigm, it appears that the common method is to fall back on a loop.

uom is a std::unordered_map

```
for(auto it = uom.begin() ; it!=uom.end(); ){
    if(it->second->toErase()) {
        delete it->second; // omit delete if using std::unique_ptr
        fpc.erase(it++);
    }else{
        ++it;
    }
}
```

//as per Scott Meyers Effective STL pg45

is this as efficient as possible?  It seams like there should be a better way to do this using something like the  erase(remove_if) paradigm but that works for unordered_map (I understand that the associative containers cannot be "re-ordered" hence the non-support of the remove_if algorithm).  Is this really the best way to erase entries from an unordered_map using a predicate? Any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is as efficient as possible.  If you want something more convenient, you could use boost's `erase_if` template - see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html).  `unordered_map` maintains a linked list of nodes in each bucket, so it's cheap to erase them.  There's no need of `remove-if type` "compaction", which suits `std::vector`'s use of contiguous memory.